# Keyword on Domain Name vs. Brand Domain Name

Tags: seo

**A solution to get quick exposure:**

Since my website just got lunched 3 days, i still have time to change my domain name. I decided to do is:

1. Pick a domain name with keyword tacked before domain name as of: {Keyword}Brand.com (looks ugly)
2. Keep it for at least 1 year till my site get fair exposure, just to reach to my competitors.
3. Move back to Brand.com (Probably). I know i will loose ranks, but it won't be hard to bring it back because the website is already being exposed and used by many.

**Question:**

Do you believe this is a good temporary solution?

Hence, The keyword is non-English word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So get everyone to learn your name and then change it and get everyone to learn your new name?  Does that sound like a good idea? Why not build a strong foundation and then **keep building upon it?** Races are *marathons*, not sprints. Think long term, not short term. If you're actually good at what you do you will eventually outrank your competitors for all of your keywords even without your keywords being in your domain name. If you're not good at what you, then hacks and tricks like this won't help you anyway.